# Can I style non-buttons to use button's block/inline-block hybrid display?

Tags: html, css, button, css-float

When you set a button element to display:block it dominates its vertical space like a block while still calculating its size based on its contents like an inline-block.  This seems like a really useful behavior.  Is it possible to make other elements behave this way?

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/h3t04frYrWHKRlEcGTA5)

I can accomplish a similar method of display using floats and clears, but it causes havoc on nearby content that isn't tailored to it.

I can accomplish it more sanely by wrapping each element and making the outer element display:block while the inner element is display:inline-block.  This requires extra markup though.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for, can you add more detail?

Comment: Like you say, `float:left; clear:left;` achieves this, the question is what sort of 'havoc' are you talking about. Applying this to your code causes no problems.

Comment: Do you mean the Anchor elements should not stretch across the window?

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: @Godwin try putting inline content between the floated elements.  They remove themselves from the flow, thus not really acting like button does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `display: table`.

Such a “table” shrinks to just fit its content, and if the content is not a `display: table-row` or `display: table-cell` then it is just treated as if it were inside a single-cell table. You can also center it horizontally using `auto` margins.

I changed `block` to `table` in your example and it did exactly what I think you want.

(If you've thinking about the advice “don't use tables for layout” — that is referring to using *tables written in HTML markup*, not any CSS facilities.)

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't expect that to work.  I can't find any definition of what display:table is supposed to do other than to "display things like a table".